# Convert Sql query containing Group By, Distinct and Aggregate function to Linq to Entity

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am new to Linq to Entity. I tried may ways to get a simple sql query into Linq to Entity. 
Here is my query.

```
select distinct top 5 convert(varchar,CreatedDate,111) as date, count(Id)
FROM  
XYZ l 
GROUP BY convert(varchar,CreatedDate,111) order by date desc
```

I tried:

```
IQueryable<XYZ> dalMemberList = dbContext.XYZ.Where(c => c.IsDeleted == false).GroupBy(g => g.CreatedDate).OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate);
```

But it is not working for me.
Can anyone help me to convert this simple query into Linq to Entity.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Not working for me" - Do you get an error? If so what is the error Do you get different results to you are expecting? If so, what is your input data, what are the results you are getting, and what are the results you are expecting?

Comment: Insert `.Select(g => new { CreatedDate = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })` before `.OrderByDescending`

Comment: For what it is worth, in your query `DISTINCT` is redundant since you also have group by. You should not [convert to varchar without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), and it seems unnecessary to convert to varchar at all, why not just do `CONVERT(DATE, CreatedDate)`

Comment: @GarethD : It gives me error, 'System.Linq.IGrouping<System.DateTime,ABC.Models.XYZ> does not contain definition for 'CreateDate' '

Comment: @IvanStoev : Thanks bro, But it is not working for me.

Comment: Well bro, if you don't tell us what exactly *is not working for you*, I don't see how we can help.

Answer (score 0):

After a GroupBy you have to project the result to a new object. And then you can OrderBy on that new object.

[image: Result]

```
var dalMemberList = dbContext.XYZ.
Where(c => c.IsDeleted == false)
.Select(converted => new {
NewDate = converted.CreatedDate.Date.ToShortDateString(), //or other convertions
converted.IsDeleted,
converted.CreatedDate
} )
.GroupBy(g => g.NewDate)
.Select(b=> new  {
key = b.Key,
list = b.OrderByDescending(t=>t.CreatedDate).Take(5)
});
```